# Visual Studio 2010 - how to skip a method execution druing debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a method that is executed multiple times (reading data from a database) and now I need to debug a code that executes this method and it seems that it is executed until it reads all rows from the table (1000+) I just want to let the program execute this method and continue with the debugging from there.

Just to be more specific - in debug mode I use `F11` to go through the code and this behavior is frustrating. I don't want to change my break point, just want to let this method executes itself, but the only way I know for now is pressing `F5` which executes everything not just the current method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:
1. Press Shift+F11 to step back out of the function
2. Once you have stepped into the function, insert another breakpoint immediately after the loop, then press F5 to skip to that breakpoint.

Answer (score 2):

You can decorate your method with `[DebuggerStepThrough]`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Step Into` (<kbd>F11</kbd>) Use - `Step Over` (<kbd>F10</kbd>)

and if you've already entered the function (because you pressed `F11`) you can always `Step Out` using <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>F11</kbd>

For more information see [Mastering Debugging in Visual Studio 2010](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn#heading0005)